# Can you corrupt a text file by editing its character codes?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

When using Postgresql's [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html), you can create a (human readable) text file by using the plain format option. However, when opening the generated file with VScode, character codes like `SOH`, `NUL`, `SO`, etc. are displayed.

I have not come across a file mixed with character codes and normal unicode/ascii characters before. If I modify anything in this file, could I corrupt the file itself? Disregard any Postgresql operability due to modifications.

Comment: It sounds like either you have the wrong options for pg_dump, or the wrong encoding selected in VSCode.

Comment: This needs more information. What was the exact and complete command used for `pg_dump`? What version of Postgres? What OS and version? What is database encoding/locale? OS locale?  What happens if you open file in normal text editor? Add information as update to question.